# Generate "special" dictionary structure from just columns index in tsv

Tags: python, function, csv, dictionary, categorical-data

Imagine a tab separated file like this one:

```
9606    1   GO:0002576  TAS -   platelet degranulation  -   Process
9606    1   GO:0003674  ND  -   molecular_function_z    -   Function
9606    1   GO:0003674  OOO -   molecular_function_z    -   Function
9606    1   GO:0005576  IDA -   extracellular region    -   Component
9606    1   GO:0005576  TAS -   extracellular region    -   Component
9606    1   GO:0005576  OOO -   extracellular region    -   Component
9606    1   GO:0005615  HDA -   extracellular spaces    -   Component
9606    1   GO:0008150  ND  -   biological_processes    -   Process
9606    1   GO:0008150  OOO -   biological_processes    -   Process
9606    1   GO:0008150  HHH -   biological_processes    -   Process
9606    1   GO:0008150  YYY -   biological_processes    -   Process
9606    1   GO:0031012  IDA -   extracellular matrix    -   Component
9606    1   GO:0043312  TAS -   neutrophil degranulat   -   Process
```

I want to create a function that receive the number of the columns which have the information to be saved and return a "special" dictionary. And I say "special" because in my case that information is always categorical, but it could have different levels, and I am tired to write constantly the logic to add the information for each level. (Maybe there is another way of doing, that I was not able to search for, so, sorry in advanced for my ignorance)

If the specified columns are 8, 2 and 3. Being 8 the column with the highest category and 3 with the lowest, the expected dictionary could be obtained:

```
three_userinput = "8:2:3"
three = map(lambda x: int(x) - 1, three_userinput.split(":"))
DICT3 = {}
for line in file_handle:
info = line.split("\t")
    if info[three[0]] in DICT3:
        if info[three[1]] in DICT3[info[three[0]]]:
            DICT3[info[three[0]]][info[three[1]]].add(info[three[2]])
        else:
            DICT3[info[three[0]]][info[three[1]]] = set([info[three[2]]])
    else:
        DICT3[info[three[0]]] = {info[three[1]]:set([info[three[2]]])}

pprint.pprint(DICT3)
```

Output:

```
{'Component': {'1': set(['GO:0005576', 'GO:0005615', 'GO:0031012'])},
 'Function': {'1': set(['GO:0003674'])},
 'Process': {'1': set(['GO:0002576', 'GO:0008150', 'GO:0043312'])}}
```

Now with four columns 8, 2, 3 and 4. Being 8 the column with the highest category and 4 with the lowest, the expected dictionary could be obtained:

```
four_userinput = "8:2:3:4"
four = map(lambda x: int(x) - 1, four_userinput.split(":"))
DICT4 = {}
for line in file_handle:
    info = line.split("\t")
    if info[four[0]] in DICT4:
        if info[four[1]] in DICT4[info[four[0]]]:
            if info[four[2]] in DICT4[info[four[0]]][info[four[1]]]:
                DICT4[info[four[0]]][info[four[1]]][info[four[2]]].add(info[four[3]])
            else:
                DICT4[info[four[0]]][info[four[1]]][info[four[2]]] = set([info[four[3]]])
        else:
            DICT4[info[four[0]]][info[four[1]]] = {info[four[2]]:set([info[four[3]]])}
    else:
        DICT4[info[four[0]]] = {info[four[1]]:{info[four[2]]:set([info[four[3]]])}}

pprint.pprint(DICT4)
```

Output:

```
{'Component': {'1': {'GO:0005576': set(['IDA', 'OOO', 'TAS']),
                     'GO:0005615': set(['HDA']),
                     'GO:0031012': set(['IDA'])}},
 'Function': {'1': {'GO:0003674': set(['ND', 'OOO'])}},
 'Process': {'1': {'GO:0002576': set(['TAS']),
                   'GO:0008150': set(['HHH', 'ND', 'OOO', 'YYY']),
                   'GO:0043312': set(['TAS'])}}}
```

Now when I faced five levels of information (five columns), the code was almost unreadable and really really tedious... I could create specific functions for each number of levels, but.. Is there a way to design a function that could handle any number of levels?

Please If I have not explained myself properly, do not hesitate in asking me.

Comment: What kind of edit was this... there is no added value, and what annoyed me most... why my "thanks" to the community were erased?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is a [`defaultdict()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html?highlight=defaultdict#collections.defaultdict). This allows you to update entries without having to first test if they exist. i.e. if it does not exist, a default value is automatically added. As you have multiple levels, you will need to create nested defaultdicts recursively using the `build_defaultdict(levels)` function. Setting the value would also need to be recursive but the logic would be simpler:

```
import pprint
import csv
from operator import itemgetter
from collections import defaultdict


def build_defaultdict(levels):
    return defaultdict(set) if levels <= 1 else defaultdict(lambda : build_defaultdict(levels - 1))


def set_value(d, row):
    if len(row) <= 2:
        d[row[0]].add(row[1])
    else:
        d[row[0]] = set_value(d[row[0]], row[1:])

    return d


req_cols = [7, 1, 2, 3]     # counting from col 0

data = build_defaultdict(len(req_cols) - 1)
get_cols = itemgetter(*req_cols)

with open('input.csv', 'r', newline='') as f_input:
    for row in csv.reader(f_input, delimiter='\t'):
        set_value(data, get_cols(row))

pprint.pprint(data)
print(data['Component']['1']['GO:0005576'])
```

This would create your dictionary as follows:

```
defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x000002350F481B70>,
    {
        'Component': defaultdict(<function <lambda>.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x000002350F6EB378>,
            {'1': defaultdict(<class 'set'>,
                {'GO:0005576': {'IDA', 'OOO', 'TAS'},
                 'GO:0005615': {'HDA'},
                 'GO:0031012': {'IDA'}})}),
        'Function': defaultdict(<function <lambda>.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x000002350F6EB400>,
            {'1': defaultdict(<class 'set'>,
                {'GO:0003674': {'ND', 'OOO'}})}),
     'Process': defaultdict(<function <lambda>.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x00000235071BE0D0>,
            {'1': defaultdict(<class 'set'>,
                {'GO:0002576': {'TAS'},
                 'GO:0008150': {'HHH', 'ND', 'OOO', 'YYY'},
                 'GO:0043312': {'TAS'}})})})

{'TAS', 'OOO', 'IDA'}
```

It may display differently to a normal dictionary, but it works the same way as a normal dictionary. Also `itemgetter()` can be used to extract the required elements from a list into another list.

Comment: This is quickier and althought it solves the tedious part of the logic, the structure of the dictionary must be predefined for each number of levels at the beginning and also to introduce the information. I would need to find a way to re-define both parts so is valid for any number of levels.

Comment: The `defaultdict` approach can also be made recursive. I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a recursive function which does this.

```
def update_nested_dict(d, vars):
    if len(vars) > 2:
        try:
            d[vars[0]] = update_nested_dict(d[vars[0]], vars[1:])
        except KeyError:
            d[vars[0]] = update_nested_dict({}, vars[1:])
    else:
        try:
            d[vars[0]] = d[vars[0]].union([vars[1]])
        except KeyError:
            d[vars[0]] = set([vars[1]])
    return d
```

Preserving as much of your code logic and variable names as needed,

```
>>> userinput = "8:2:3:4"
>>> cols = map(lambda x: int(x) - 1, userinput.split(":"))
>>> 
>>> DICT = {}
>>> 
>>> for line in file_handle:
>>>     info = line.replace("\n", "").split("\t")
>>>     names = [info[c] for c in cols]
>>>     _ = update_nested_dict(DICT, names)
>>>
>>> for k, v in DICT.iteritems():
...  print k, v
...
Process {'1': {'GO:0002576': set(['TAS']), 'GO:0008150': set(['YYY', 'OOO', 'HHH', 'ND']), 'GO:0043312': set(['TAS'])}}
Function {'1': {'GO:0003674': set(['OOO', 'ND'])}}
Component {'1': {'GO:0005576': set(['OOO', 'IDA', 'TAS']), 'GO:0005615': set(['HDA']), 'GO:0031012': set(['IDA'])}}
```