# Nested dictionary of any depth from dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, nsdictionary, code-generation

I can create nested dictionary of dictionaries from categorical columns in pandas dataframe of depth 3 (or smaller) - see **code**.
But my solution is so hard-coded... and imagine if I want to have 'split' by 10 categorical columns.

I'm looking for something to have actions like this in pseudo-code:

```
d = {'A': ['a1','a1','a2'], 'B': ['b1','b2','b3'], 'C': ['c1','c2','c2'], 'v': [0,5,1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

dA = tree(df=d, cols=['A'])
#it gives dictionary of two dataframes
# "tree" should be some standard implementation
#a1 
#a2

dB = tree(df=d, cols=['A', 'B'])
#it give dictionary of three dataframes at lowest level
#a1_b1
#a1_b2
#a2_b3
#"tree" should be ready for any number of cols

#acces operations
dA['a1'], dB['a1'], dB['a1]['b1],...

#iteration operation (transpose is just for example)
dA = dA.iter.T #transposes every dataframe
dB = dB.iter.T #transposes every dataframe on lowest level i.e. dB['a1]['b1].T, dB['a1]['b2].T, ...

#some operations will require access to dictionary keys to make sense or to have enough flexibility:
dA.iter.to_csv(str(key)+'csv')
#produces a1.csv, a2.csv
dB.iter.to_csv(str(key)+'csv')
#produces a1_b1.csv, a1_b2.csv, a2_b3.csv
```

Basically: to easily created nested dictionary of any depth from dataframe, create functions data operate at 'key-level' of any depth and iterate over whole dictionary without writing code for every level.

My **code**:

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import defaultdict

# sample dataframe
d = {'A': ['a1','a1','a2'], 'B': ['b1','b2','b3'], 'C': ['c1','c2','c2'], 'v': [0,5,1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

# make dictionary of dataframes based on categorical column, every categroy is a key to dataframe
def dict_dfs_based_on_cat(df, col):
    Cat = df[col].unique()
    dictDFbasedOnCat = {elem: pd.DataFrame for elem in Cat}
    for key in dictDFbasedOnCat.keys(): 
        dictDFbasedOnCat[key] = df[:][df[col]==key]
    return dictDFbasedOnCat

#1st level 
di_A = dict_dfs_based_on_cat(df, 'A')

#2nd level
di_A_B= {}
for a in di_A:
    di_A_B[a] = dict_dfs_based_on_cat(di_A[a], 'B')

#3rd level
di_A_B_C = defaultdict(dict)
for a in di_A:
    for b in di_A_B[a]:
        di_A_B_C[a][b] = dict_dfs_based_on_cat(di_A_B[a][b],'C')

#operations on 3rd level
def iter_di(msg, func, di):
    print(msg)
    for a in di:
        for b in di[a]:
            for c in di[a][b]:
                func(a, b, c, di)

def save(a, b, c, di):
    di[a][b][c].to_csv(str(a)+'_'+str(b)+'_'+str(c)+'.csv', index=False)

#sample operation
iter_di('saving', save, di_A_B_C)

#a1_b1_c1.csv
#a1_b2_c2.csv
#a2_b3_c2.csv
```

Comment: The solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49449356/generate-special-dictionary-structure-from-just-columns-index-in-tsv/) could possibly help. Instead of looping through lines in a string, you could loop through your dataframes and retrieve the necessary columns.

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted may have a few problems:

- `d = {'A': ['a1','a1','a2'], 'B': ['b1','b2','b3'], 'C': 'c1','c2','c2'], 'v': [0,5,1]}` has a missing closing bracket (obvious fix)
- `return dictDFbasedOnCat` may be indented incorrectly.

In any case, after assuming what the code should be and running it, `di_A_B_C` returns

```
>>> di_A_B_C
defaultdict(<type 'dict'>, {'a1': {'b1': {'c1':     A   B   C  v
0  a1  b1  c1  0}, 'b2': {'c2':     A   B   C  v
1  a1  b2  c2  5}}, 'a2': {'b3': {'c2':     A   B   C  v
2  a2  b3  c2  1}}})
```

---

This result can be matched with a recursive function:

```
def update_nested_dict(d, vars, frame):
    if len(vars) > 2:
        try:
            d[vars[0]] = update_nested_dict(d[vars[0]], vars[1:], frame)
        except KeyError:
            d[vars[0]] = update_nested_dict({}, vars[1:], frame)
    else:
        try:
            d[vars[0]].update({vars[1]: frame})
        except KeyError:
            d[vars[0]] = {vars[1]: frame}
    return d
```

You can define a function which then takes a `DataFrame` object and the exact order of the columns you want to sort, which spits out a `defaultdict` object:

```
def dataframe_dict(df, cols=None):

    if cols is None:
        cols = df.keys()

    di = {}
    df_col_inds = dict(zip(df.keys(), range(len(df.keys()))))
    df_col_inds = [df_col_inds[c] for c in cols]
    for v in df.values:
        _ = update_nested_dict(di, v[df_col_inds], pd.DataFrame(dict(zip(df.keys(), v[:,None]))))

    return defaultdict(dict, di)
```

E.g., matching your `di_A_B_C`:

```
>>> dataframe_dict(df, ['A', 'B', 'C'])
defaultdict(<type 'dict'>, {'a1': {'b1': {'c1':     A   B   C  v
0  a1  b1  c1  0}, 'b2': {'c2':     A   B   C  v
0  a1  b2  c2  5}}, 'a2': {'b3': {'c2':     A   B   C  v
0  a2  b3  c2  1}}})
```

Using all columns:

```
>>> dataframe_dict(df) # Same as dataframe_dict(df, df.keys()) = dataframe_dict(df, ['A', 'B', 'C', 'v'])
defaultdict(<type 'dict'>, {'a1': {'b1': {'c1': {0L:     A   B   C  v
0  a1  b1  c1  0}}, 'b2': {'c2': {5L:     A   B   C  v
0  a1  b2  c2  5}}}, 'a2': {'b3': {'c2': {1L:     A   B   C  v
0  a2  b3  c2  1}}}})
```

Random order of columns:

```
>>> dataframe_dict(df, ['v', 'C', 'A'])
defaultdict(<type 'dict'>, {0L: {'c1': {'a1':     A   B   C  v
0  a1  b1  c1  0}}, 1L: {'c2': {'a2':     A   B   C  v
0  a2  b3  c2  1}}, 5L: {'c2': {'a1':     A   B   C  v
0  a1  b2  c2  5}}})
```

Comment: @drooze Thanks a lot for help and correction of code (some misedits from my side during copy-paste).
I'll check this recursvie approach.

Comment: @drooze I was thinking about this and basicaly I need to dyanamically build a tree. In leaves there will be specific dataframes. To perform my actions, I need to iterate on leaves.

Comment: @QuantChristo update the question with a very concise example on what your actions are, you'll get better answers that way.

Comment: @drooze I hope that now my pseudo-code is more clear.

Comment: @QuantChristo I hope you're not looking to implement a new method in `pandas`, because that's what the syntax `pd.tree` means; maybe you want to define a function called `tree`? Also, it is unclear why `dB = dA = pd.tree(df=d, cols=['A', 'B'])` would expect `dB.iter.T` to transpose on lower levels than `dA.iter.T`, since they both point to the same reference - that's a multiple assignment operation you have there. Maybe you mean that `tree()` should return two objects because you specified two objects in `['A', 'B']`?

Comment: @drooze For sure, I don't want implement anything new, so I changed pd.tree into "tree", but it'd be great if pandas has such functionality. 
`dB=dA` my mistake it should be `dB = tree(df=d, cols=['A', 'B'])`

Answer (score 0):

This may help partially if you transform your dictionary of dictionaries into list of lists.

```
import itertools

d = [['attrs',['a1','a1','a2']], ['B',['b1','b2','b3']], ['C',['c1','c2','c2']], ['v',[0,5,1]]]

list_of_items = [k[1] for k in d]
z = list(itertools.product(*list_of_items))
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I've dataframe and `d` is only for make example more concrete.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly answer to my question, but it solves my problem.
I don't need to have nested dictionary of dataframes of any depth, because I don't need to store intermediate results - just perform some actions on slice of dataframe and store it in csv.

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'A': ['a1','a1','a2'], 'B': ['b1','b2','b3'], 'C': ['c1','c2','c2'], 'v': [0,5,1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df = df.set_index(['A','B','C'])

for i in set(df.index):
    df_sel = df.loc[i].reset_index()
    df_sel = df_sel.T #or any other operation on dataframe
    df_sel.to_csv(str(i) + '.csv')
```